# Показать прошлый рейс в записи

Tags: sql, oracle

Существует таблица с расписанием поездок поездов:

```
create table atest (
TR_ID NUMBER(9),
TR_START DATE,
TR_END DATE,
TR_FROMSTART VARCHAR2(255),
TR_FROMEND VARCHAR2(255) )

TR_ID   TR_START              TR_END             TR_FROMSTART TR_FROMEND 
    1   01.06.2020 4:50:00    01.06.2020 7:50:00       MSK         KZN  
    1   01.06.2020 9:35:00    01.06.2020 13:00:00      КZN         ANP  
    2   03.06.2020 15:35:00   03.06.2020 18:30:00      MSK         SPB  
    2   05.06.2020 5:15:00    05.06.2020 10:30:00      SPB         MSK  
    3   05.06.2020 12:05:00   05.06.2020 12:05:00      MSK         NSB  
    3   08.06.2020 17:05:00   09.06.2020 1:50:00       NSB         MSK  
    1   10.06.2020 12:30:00   10.06.2020 16:00:00      ANP         KZN  
    1   12.06.2020 17:20:00   13.06.2020 5:35:00       KZN         MSK  
    2   15.06.2020 5:15:00    15.06.2020 10:30:00      MSK         ANP  
    2   15.06.2020 12:05:00   15.06.2020 17:50:00      ANP         KZN
```

В таблице столбцы отвечают за следующие значения: `TR_ID` - идентификатор поезда, `TR_START и TR_END` - время выезда и приезда поезда, `TR_FROMSTART и TR_FROMEND` - пункты отбытия и прибытия поезда.

Задача следующая: Создать запрос, который выведет такие же столбцы, но добавит к ним столбцы с временем отправки и прибытия предыдущего рейса этого поезда, рейс обязательно должен быть в предыдущий день или раньше.

Пример того, что должно получиться:

```
      TR_ID  TR_START                TR_END             TR_FROMSTART TR_FROMEND       LASTRACE_ST 
            1   01.06.2020 4:50:00    01.06.2020 7:50:00       MSK         KZN             0  
            1   01.06.2020 9:35:00    01.06.2020 13:00:00      КZN         ANP           01.06.2020 4:50:00   
            2   03.06.2020 15:35:00   03.06.2020 18:30:00      MSK         SPB             0
            2   05.06.2020 5:15:00    05.06.2020 10:30:00      SPB         MSK           05.06.2020 5:15:00   
            3   05.06.2020 12:05:00   05.06.2020 12:05:00      MSK         NSB             0
            3   08.06.2020 17:05:00   09.06.2020 1:50:00       NSB         MSK           08.06.2020 17:05:00 
.................................................... и т.д.
```

Пробовал сделать задачу многими способами, самый близкий был с `NTH_VALUE`:

```
select distinct  a.tr_id, trunc(a.tr_start), a.tr_fromstart, a.tr_fromend,
NTH_VALUE(a.tr_start, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY a.tr_id ORDER BY a.tr_start DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) lastrace_st,
NTH_VALUE(a.tr_end, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY a.tr_id ORDER BY a.tr_start DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) lastrace_end 
       from atest a
order by trunc(a.tr_start)
```

Однако, данные выбираются некорректно - берется предпоследний рейс по поезду в целом, а не предыдущий.

Comment: Используйте две копии таблицы. Вторую соединяйте по номеру поезда и меньшей дате, и вот из ней выбирайте первую по убыванию даты запись. Если результат запрос содержит небольшое количество записей, то можно и коррелированный подзапрос в списке вывода использовать. PS. Не помню, умеет ли Оракл LATERAL JOIN...

Comment: Да, Вы правы в логике, я так и подумал. Основная сложность как раз возникает с "меньшей датой", не знаю, как их сравнивать между собой.

Comment: Дык и я не знаю... особенно если учесть, что дата убытия и прибытия могут не совпадать, и неясно, какую дату брать для проверки на "предыдущий день или раньше". А так-то просто - `ON TRUNC(t1.somedate, 'DAY') > TRUNC(t2.somedate, 'DAY')`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151

Comment: Для проверки брать дату убытия.

Comment: Попробовал объединить, как Вы сказали, по TRUNC(a.TR_START, 'DAY') > TRUNC(am.TR_START, 'DAY') , при этом получается что-то похожее на правду, но не совсем - один день сравнивается со всеми остальными, то есть по примеру из моей таблицы за 15 число таблица отберет все предыдущие рейсы, а не один.

Comment: Ну так  а потом для каждой записи из первой копии берёшь самую последнюю запись из второй копии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e893f95a80548652b2531b35473e12ee)):

```
select * 
from atest t1
outer apply (
    select 
        max (tr_start) keep (dense_rank last order by t2.tr_start asc) last_start,
        max (tr_end)   keep (dense_rank last order by t2.tr_end   asc) last_end
    from atest t2
    where t2.tr_id  = t1.tr_Id 
    and   t2.tr_fromend = t1.tr_fromstart  
    and   t2.tr_end < t1.tr_start
)
order by t1.tr_start
```

Результат:

```
TR_ID TR_START         TR_END           DEP ARR LAST_START       LAST_END        
----- ---------------- ---------------- --- --- ---------------- ----------------
    1 01.06.2020 04:50 01.06.2020 07:50 MSK KZN                                  
    1 01.06.2020 09:35 01.06.2020 13:00 KZN ANP 01.06.2020 04:50 01.06.2020 07:50
    2 03.06.2020 15:35 03.06.2020 18:30 MSK SPB                                  
    2 05.06.2020 05:15 05.06.2020 10:30 SPB MSK 03.06.2020 15:35 03.06.2020 18:30
    3 05.06.2020 12:05 05.06.2020 12:05 MSK NSB                                  
    3 08.06.2020 17:05 09.06.2020 01:50 NSB MSK 05.06.2020 12:05 05.06.2020 12:05
    1 10.06.2020 12:30 10.06.2020 16:00 ANP KZN 01.06.2020 09:35 01.06.2020 13:00
    1 12.06.2020 17:20 13.06.2020 05:35 KZN MSK 10.06.2020 12:30 10.06.2020 16:00
    2 15.06.2020 05:15 15.06.2020 10:30 MSK ANP 05.06.2020 05:15 05.06.2020 10:30
    2 15.06.2020 12:05 15.06.2020 17:50 ANP KZN 15.06.2020 05:15 15.06.2020 10:30
```

Так как, описание не совсем совпадает с ожидаемым результатом, пара пояснений:

- `t2.tr_fromend = t1.tr_fromstart` - рейс сначало должен прибыть на туже станцию, с которой он отправится в следующий рейс
- `t2.tr_end < t1.tr_start` - рейс может сразу же отправится до следующей станци назначения; для условия: *рейс обязательно должен быть в предыдущий день или раньше*, надо заменуть на `t2.tr_end < trunc (t1.tr_start)`

Comment: Спасибо! Но при выполнении кода выдает ошибку ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @Gipnomanul Добавил ссылку на фиддле, всё работает. Какая у вас версия БД?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не уточнил. Оракл у меня версии 11, а как я сейчас прочел, функцию outer apply ввели с 12 версии..

Comment: @Gipnomanul Надо было указать. Вам надо будет тоже самое сделать с классическиим left join. Попробуйте сами, а я как немного освобожусь, добавлю на фиддле, обновлю ссылку и дам знать.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: @Gipnomanul добавил [на фиддле пример для 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e893f95a80548652b2531b35473e12ee). На скорую руку и не уверен, что там всё правильно, но попробуйте.

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо большое!!